# QT 5.9.2 not detecting iOS kit, and iOS tab is missing in Preferences

Tags: ios, qt, macos-high-sierra

Running macOS High Sierra and QT 5.9.2 
Tried to remove and reinstall, both with online and offline installers, but iOS kit does not show up in QT Creator. I see the related files are installed and available. What could be missing?

Comment: XCode and Developer Tools for XCode?

Comment: The same here. Both XCode and Developer Tools are installed and work flawlessly. But the iOS kit is missing.